# Can't connect to database with php

Tags: php

How come I can't connect to database?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_query' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp2\htdocs\tutorials\abc.php on line 14

```
<?php


$user = 'root' ; 
$pass = 'gfcf' ; 

$db = 'testdb' ; 

$con = new mysql('localhost', $user , $pass , $db) or die("UNABLE TO CONNECT");

$selected = mysql_select_db($db,con) 


mysql_query(" CREATE TABLE people 
(

firstname varchar(15)

gender varchar()


)");



?>
```

Comment: you're mixing mysqli and mysql

Comment: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use. You should to the PHP website instead.

Comment: Missing `$` for `con` in `$selected = mysql_select_db($db,con)`  if anything but that is `mysqli_*` syntax. That alone will put a damper on things.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing mysql_ and mysqli_ functions:

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', $user , $pass , $db) or die("UNABLE TO CONNECT");
$selected = mysqli_select_db($con,$db) 
mysqli_query($con, " CREATE TABLE people 
(
  firstname varchar(15)
  gender varchar()
)");
```

Comment: hey that's cool. I guess making answer a community wiki right away is waaay out of my league.

Comment: *"You're mixing mysql_ and mysqli_ functions:"* so were you John lol! I fixed the missing `i` ;-)

Comment: I know the feeling John. Always a pleasure though, contributing to wiki.